# What type of fan would I need to induce the lift of a 200 lbs object?

Tags: materials, design

I know this might sound ridiculous, but I am attempting to make a fan designed to induce lift of a 200 lbs object. By 'fan', I mean like the fans that lift a drone off the ground. I can only have a maximum of 3 fans.

I am trying to lift the object at least 5 feet of the ground.

Do you know what type of fans I would need, and/or the RPM of the fans? I am little bit confused on what to ask since there aren't any other questions like this. Also I am a beginner to engineering.

Comment: Could you add a sketch of what you have in mind? It's not very clear whether the fans are to be attached to a drone or what the object might look like otherwise.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Fan design is complex. Some of the factors that need to be considered are: fan diameter, the number of blades, the shape of the blades, the angle of the blades, power supplied to the blades, rotation speed of the blades, materials used, flexibility of the blades & detrimental airflow characteristics produced by the blades, such as turbulence & vortexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start out by doing a momentum ballance.  You want to lift 200 pounds, so that means you need to push down on air with 200 pounds (890 N).  That means you need to move (890 * Kg * m/s) of air every second.

Note that this gives you a tradeoff.  You could, for example, push 10 kg of air per second down at 89 m/s, 100 kg per second of air down at 8.9 m/s, etc.  In theory, you get the same lift force either way.  Basically you can push a little air a lot, or a lot of air a little.

However, consider the power requirement.  The kinetic energy of a moving mass is (½ * m * V<sup>2</sup>).  Note that annoying V<sup>2</sup> term.  It says that pushing a little air a lot requires more power than pushing a lot of air a little.  This is why sail planes have such wide wings.  Power usage is a primary design consideration, so the large area being swept across by the wings each time unit allows for pushing a lot of air, which requires imparting less velocity to the air, which saves power since that's proportional to the square of the velocity.

To get a start on your numbers, let's pick a air velocity and see what we get.  I'm going to pick about half the speed of sound as example, so 165 m/s.  This means you have to move 5.4 kg of air per second.  At 20 °C, that's about 4500 liters of air per second.  The power you'd be imparting to the moving air is 73 kW.

The area of that jet (for now assuming constant velocity crossection just to get a rough feel where we're at) is (4.5 m<sup>3</sup>/s)/(165 m/s) = 0.027 m<sup>2</sup>.  That's a circular jet  186 mm in diameter, or about 7.3 inches.  Of course the flow crossection won't be constant, so the diameter will need to be bigger, and the power higher because some air will be faster than the average and some slower, but the faster will require disproportionately more power.  I don't want to get into those fluid dynamics details here.  I'll arbitrarily say the area needs to be about 50% larger, so 9 inches in diameter.  I'll also round up the 73 kW to 100 kW.

So, we have as a very rough starting point:

165 m/s average jet speed
  9 inch jet diameter
  100 kW power required

From there you can scale things accordingly.  The area is inversely proportional to the jet speed, and the diameter goes with the square root of the area.  The power goes with the jet speed.

For example, let's see what we get with 1/10 the jet speed:

16.5 m/s average jet speed
  28 inch jet diameter
  10 kW power required

Again, these are very rough numbers with a lot of simplifying assumptions.  The point is to give you a ballpark idea, and a basis for making relative tradeoffs from.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you need to find a way to develop about 1000 Newtons of upward force by accelerating a mass of air downward. You can make tradeoffs between the amount (mass) of air and the acceleration you give it.

[Here is one solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-powered_helicopter) that uses a very large area and low velocity/acceleration, in order to match the capabilities of a human being as a power source.

If you use other power sources, the system can be afford to be less efficient, leading to other solutions that use higher velocities/accelerations and smaller areas.